# Visible intersectionObserver

Tags: javascript, intersection-observer

I am trying to learn about Javascript's IntersectionObserver.

After reading several articles and the documentation I have decided to make a CodePen to try it myself: [IntersectionObserver CodePen](https://codepen.io/lpato/pen/jKwbQX)

I would like to display the "block that is visible" on the top message. The CodePen "almost" works, but not completely. Sometimes it shows the correct block, sometimes it doesn't.

Here is my JS:

```
let message = document.querySelector('#block-number');

// INTERSECTION OBSERVER STUFF
const io = new IntersectionObserver(entries => {
   if(entries[0].isIntersecting) {
    message.innerHTML = entries[0].target.textContent;
  }
}, {
    threshold: [.25]
});

// ELEMENTS TO OBSERVE
const blk1 = document.querySelector('#block1');
const blk2 = document.querySelector('#block2');
const blk3 = document.querySelector('#block3');
const blk4 = document.querySelector('#block4');
const blk5 = document.querySelector('#block5');
const blk6 = document.querySelector('#block6');

// START OBSERVING ELEMENTS
io.observe(blk1);
io.observe(blk2);
io.observe(blk3);
io.observe(blk4);
io.observe(blk5);
io.observe(blk6);
```

Any ideas on what i am doing wrong?

i have also tried (without luck) something like:

```
if(entries[0].intersectionRatio !== 0)
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The function passed to the IntersectionObserved is executed when the intersection state changes. So what happens when you are at block 3 and scroll a bit so block 4 is shown? The intersection changes for block 4 and so the message is changed. WHen you scroll back up the intersection is changed again for block 4, but it does not enter the if condition. The intersection for block 3 on the other hand is not changed - it was visible before, even though not fully, it's visible still.

There are few ways you can fix this.
One is to define intersection ratio, and going above and below that ratio will be considered change in the state (pass options hash as second argument, containing `threshold` key with value 0 - 1, e.g. 0.5 for 50% visibility)

You can also add the same observer for all of the blocks and iterate trough `entries` in the function, checking which block has the best intersection ratio.

Comment: do you mean something like what i have now? Still not quite working!   :(   please see the changed question!

Comment: @LuisBento Try using `entries.forEach (entry) ` instead of `entries[0]`

Answer (score 1):

You have set the threshold to 25%.

The problem with this, is that the previous block leaves its last 25% of the viewport **after** the next block enters the viewport by 25%.

This was easy to see with the following console.log:

```
console.log(entries[0].target.textContent, ": ", entries[0].intersectionRatio)
```

```js
let message = document.querySelector('#block-number');

// INTERSECTION OBSERVER STUFF
const io = new IntersectionObserver(entries => {
   if(entries[0].isIntersecting ) {
    console.log(entries[0].target.textContent, ": ", entries[0].intersectionRatio)
    message.innerHTML = entries[0].target.textContent;
  }
}, {
    threshold: [.25]
});

// ELEMENTS TO OBSERVE
const blk1 = document.querySelector('#block1');
const blk2 = document.querySelector('#block2');
const blk3 = document.querySelector('#block3');
const blk4 = document.querySelector('#block4');
const blk5 = document.querySelector('#block5');
const blk6 = document.querySelector('#block6');

// START OBSERVING ELEMENTS
io.observe(blk1);
io.observe(blk2);
io.observe(blk3);
io.observe(blk4);
io.observe(blk5);
io.observe(blk6);
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: roboto;
}

.center {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.container {
  background-color: #eee;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.message {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: #ef9b8d;
  color: white;
}

.blocks {
  padding-top: 100px;
}

.block {
  height: 85vh;
  width: 90vw;
  margin: 0 auto 15vh;
  background-color: #999;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="message center">Displaying &nbsp;<span id="block-number">Block 1</span></div>
  
  <div class="blocks">
    <div id="block1" class="block center">Block 1</div>
    <div id="block2" class="block center">Block 2</div>
    <div id="block3" class="block center">Block 3</div>
    <div id="block4" class="block center">Block 4</div>
    <div id="block5" class="block center">Block 5</div>
    <div id="block6" class="block center">Block 6</div>
  </div>
```

To fix this, simply **raise the threshold**. (Depending on how much of the block needs to enter the viewport for you to consider it the current block)

Demo:

```js
let message = document.querySelector('#block-number');

// INTERSECTION OBSERVER STUFF
const io = new IntersectionObserver(entries => {
   if(entries[0].isIntersecting ) {
    console.log(entries[0].target.textContent, ": ", entries[0].intersectionRatio)
    message.innerHTML = entries[0].target.textContent;
  }
}, {
    threshold: [.8] // raised the threshold
});

// ELEMENTS TO OBSERVE
const blk1 = document.querySelector('#block1');
const blk2 = document.querySelector('#block2');
const blk3 = document.querySelector('#block3');
const blk4 = document.querySelector('#block4');
const blk5 = document.querySelector('#block5');
const blk6 = document.querySelector('#block6');

// START OBSERVING ELEMENTS
io.observe(blk1);
io.observe(blk2);
io.observe(blk3);
io.observe(blk4);
io.observe(blk5);
io.observe(blk6);
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: roboto;
}

.center {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.container {
  background-color: #eee;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.message {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: #ef9b8d;
  color: white;
}

.blocks {
  padding-top: 100px;
}

.block {
  height: 85vh;
  width: 90vw;
  margin: 0 auto 15vh;
  background-color: #999;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="message center">Displaying &nbsp;<span id="block-number">Block 1</span></div>
  
  <div class="blocks">
    <div id="block1" class="block center">Block 1</div>
    <div id="block2" class="block center">Block 2</div>
    <div id="block3" class="block center">Block 3</div>
    <div id="block4" class="block center">Block 4</div>
    <div id="block5" class="block center">Block 5</div>
    <div id="block6" class="block center">Block 6</div>
  </div>
```

Comment: yes, actually threshold: .25 fixed it for me. Thanks!